Cancel button still showing despite setting it to false
For some reason, the CANCEL button is showing in my SweetAlert2 popup even though I have set it to false? Has anyone else come across this?
Sample code:
  Swal.fire({
                title: _title,
                text: _desc,
                icon: 'warning',
                showCancelButton: false,
                confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                confirmButtonText: 'Yes, proceed!'
            }).then((result) => {
                if (result.value) {
                    isLoading(1);
                    $.get("ajax/asset/sunset_asset.aspx", { id: assetId, status: assetNewStatus }, function (data) {
                        if (data == "OK") {
                            toastr.success(_responseOK, 'Success');
                            refreshResults();
                        } else {
                            toastr.error(data, 'Error');
                        }
                        isLoading(0);
                    });
                }
            });



where does the title and text get their value? can you make '_title' and '_desc' just to try?

@kapitan it is set by passing data to a surrounding function. In this case, is is the Sunset asset? and the description below in the example screenshot.

understood. are you sure that you only have one Swal.fire function?
